angle of $\frac{\sum_i a_i e^{j\theta_i}}{\sum_i a_i}$
Let $\displaystyle a=\sum_{i=1}^N a_i\ne 0$ be a sum of $N$ complex numbers, $a_i$'s.  Suppose we rotate each $a_i$ by a small angle $\theta_i$, i.e. $\vert \theta_i\vert \le \phi$ and, say, $\phi=\pi/8$. Let's call the new sum $\displaystyle \hat a=\sum_{i=1}^N a_i e^{j\theta_i}$.
How much does the angle change from $a$ to $\hat a$? In particular, is it bounded by $\phi$?  I.e. $\displaystyle \left \vert \mathrm{arg}\left(\frac{\hat a}{a}\right)\right \vert \le \phi$?
Geometrically, it appears so, but I haven't been able to prove or disprove it.  Help would be appreciated.

Example: $a_1 = e^{i \phi}$ and $a_2 = -e^{-i\phi}$ with some “small” $\phi > 0$. Then
$$\arg(a_1 + a_2) = \pi/2$$
and
$$
 \arg(e^{-2i \phi} a_1 + e^{2i \phi} a_2) = \arg(\overline{a_1} + \overline{a_2}) = -\pi/2 \, .
$$
So small changes in the arguments of the summands can cause large changes in the argument of the sum.

I appreciated the answer.  Yeah, so the answer is no in general.  It's interesting to consider its implications:  If we rotate all components $a_i$ by the same angle, say $\theta$, then apparently the sum $\hat a$ is also rotated by $\theta$.  However, if $\theta_i$'s are not the same but have small variance (i.e. $\phi$), then $\hat a$ may not be rotated approximately by $\theta$ at all.

@syeh_106: Do does this answer your question, or is anything still unclear?

It does!  Thanks a lot!
